# finding depth of a tree?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am very new to binary tree and recursion. My program is to find the height of the tree but I am a bit confused as to why my program doesn't work.

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
}

int heightOfTree(Node node){
    if(node ==NULL)
    {
         return 0;
    }
    else
    {
       int lheight=heightOfTree(node->left);
       int rheight = heightOfTree(node->right);
       if(lheight>rheight)
       {
           return lheight;
       }
       else
       {
           return rheight;
       }
    }
}
```

I followed a pseudocode online so I implemented it myself because I don't want to just copy and paste. I tried to insert a lot of nodes but When I run my program I always get 0 height? Thank you

Comment: Construct a tree with a root node and one leaf node and step through your code by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return lheight + 1;
```

and

```
return rheight + 1;
```

You need to increment the height at each level.